# How to include a leaflet map (html widget) into a Word or PowerPoint document?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown, powerpoint, htmlwidgets

I teach Leaflet to my students to map and analyze spatial data.

I would like them to present some of their work in PowerPoint, Word, and/or PDF while maintaining the interactive features of the leaflet maps.

Is that achievable without Rmarkdown? How can one integrate a html widget into Word or Powerpoint?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think that's possible if you want the interactive features:  Leaflet needs a browser that can run Javascript, and I don't think PowerPoint or Word do that.  PDF viewers generally don't.  Your students should produce their presentations or reports in some HTML format, e.g. ioslides or Slidy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is what I thought after searching for some time. Thus, there is not be a Microsoft add-in that would help? I really did not want to go reporting results over html format file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing in PowerPoint.
I tried the official web browser add-in, but it doesn't support folium, leaflet.

Another great guy made an add-in called LiveWeb which can work for javalet. It's supposed to support HTML embed, but my PowerPoint version is 2019. LiveWeb is not supported.

But you can try it if you like.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In addition to the other suggestions, your students might be able to embed leaflet maps in a simple HTML file or files, store them locally or on a web server, then link to them via an action setting in their PowerPoint file.